# How to activate an iPhone 5 with an inactivated SIM card

Tags: iphone

I would like to use my iPhone 5 with an inactivated SIM card. I tried restoring using iTunes but each time I turn the phone on it starts all over again and asks me what language, what country, enter pass code etc. It connects to my Wi-Fi and then wants to know if I want to restore from iCloud, iTunes, or start new. I've tried this several times.

I would like to test this phone out before I activate the nano sim card. My old phone is an iPhone 3 and uses a larger SIM card so I don't want to deactivate that until I am sure the new one will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't activate the phone using an inactive sim card. However, if the phone is unlocked you can use any active sim card to activate it.

Take one from a family member or a friend. It's a few seconds process.